# Got errs with puppeteer and node-sass running npm i

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, puppeteer, node-sass

I have a double problem.
The work environment is in Vue and Nuxt, with a mac M1 pro.
Until last week, I had no problems, everything was running perfect. They changed my mac and the world stopped running.

I download 2 repos, but when running npm i, one explodes with puppeteer and the other with node-sass.
`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! error 1 npm ERR! puppeteer@8.0.0 install:`nodeinstall.js `npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@8.0.0 install script.`

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! error 1 npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall:` node scripts/build.js `npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.`

I am using the correct version of Node.
I tried deleting the package-lock.json and the node_modules, clearing the npm cache, and running npm i again, and no, it breaks.
I tried installing those specific packages outside of npm i, and I get the same error.
I tried creating a .npmrc file with
`registry=https://registry.npmjs.org always-auth=true //registry.npmjs.org/: "token"` 
I am using the same package.json and the same repos as my peers. They also have mac M1 and have no problem.
On Github we have the same permissions.

Any idea what is happening?
Thank you very much in advance \o/

Comment: Can you install those packages themselves in a brand new project? Aka, is your NPM broken or is the repo broken? Double-check the version of NPM they are using. Also, consider giving a try to yarn, you may have more verbose results in terms of debugging.

Comment: i will try, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: BTW. The problem is not with those packages separately, since I can install them outside of npm install, the problem is within those repos, even though I install them manually, it doesn't take them and keeps giving errors
Now trying with yarn

Comment: Yarn got the same error with puppeteer o0

Comment: Is it a public Github repo? Got some git hooks or alike? Any specific npmrc config you buddies have?

Comment: Nops, its private. We all have the same permissions, cloned the same repo and have the same configuration, but in my mac have this unsolved issues. So I changed my mac, but the problem persist o0

BTW, muchas gracias for your answers and ideas \o/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sass` instead of `node-sass`. This is because `node-sass` has been deprecated.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Works all the same, no need to make any other changes

Comment: Muchas gracias Abraham. 
I had no problems with node-sass, I could install it outside of NPM install, but the repo wouldn't run anyway. 
The whole problem stemmed from the fact that I'm on a work machine, and the "antivirus" blocked github, letting me clone, but not doing much else. 
On Macs the installation would break with the node-sass and puppeteer packages, on Windows the installation wouldn't even run. Now I got some special permissions, and I can run everything without problems